# Django randomly ordering model instances

Tags: python, django, django-models

Does anyone know of a better way to randomly order models instances when showing them?

I'm going to have a lot of instances returned and I'm not trying to kill my server with `order_by('?')`

Comment: Why does your title tag about URL pattern ordering when your question is about model instance ordering?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I have no idea, that's a good question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want all queryset list, you can use python way.

First you should convert django instances to list

```
queryset_list = list(YourModel.objects.all())
```

and you can shuffle the `queryset_list`.

```
from random import shuffle
shuffle(queryset_list)
```

I think it's pretty faster then using `order_by('?')`

Comment: So I would do this in the view and pass it in as context?

Comment: I actually need to filter them

Comment: Did you mean that you want to filter that queryset? Then just filter all queries before shuffle, and shuffle them just right before give to temlpate.

Answer (score 0):

import

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator

def index(request):    
    finals = Final.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(list(finals), 10)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    contacts = paginator.get_page(page)
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'contacts': contacts})
```

Use Like this

Comment: How does this randomly order the instances?